# How to patch a method in Classes.pas

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I need to patch a method in Classes.pas

(TReader.ReadString - I want to force it to use a specified codepage, not the system default).

If I copy Classes.pas into my project,I will end up having to rebuild the entire VCL. Is there any (easy) way to patch a method at runtime?

Comment: Are you sure there's no configuration-based approach to achieve what you need? Patching classes.pas should really be your LAST resort...

Comment: Yes, there is a configuration-based approach - changing the locale for the whole system!

The problem is that D2009 doesn't look to be fully Unicode (I think the DFM's still contain AnsiStrings). I want to be able to load different resource dll's (English/Japanese/Chinese/Korean) on a single machine, *without* changing the system locale

Comment: DFMs are processed as UTF8, to my knowledge.

Comment: After successfully patching TReader.ReadString, I have found that there are some AnsiStrings in the DFM's, but not the ones causing me problems...

Comment: Barry, thanks for your answer/comments. Still haven't sorted out what exactly went wrong with our localisation stuff, but somehow codepage 932 (SHIFT-JIS) text got written into the .dfn files instead of UTF8. This whole patching exercise has turned into something of an unnecessary diversion...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found VCLFixPack:

https://www.idefixpack.de/blog/bugfix-units/vclfixpack-10/

I used the techniques from this to replace the method I wanted to patch at runtime.

Answer (score 20):

Modifying the implementation side of Classes.pas will not require recompiling everything. Delphi figures out if a unit needs to be recompiled by an algorithm that looks roughly like this:

- If DCU found:

  - Is DCU format out of date (old version of compiler)? If so, need source to recompile or compile-time error.
  - Is the source on the path? If so, if it's newer than the DCU, recompile
  - For each used unit:

    - Repeat analysis when loading
    - For each used symbol ("import": type, variable, routine, initialized constant etc.) from that unit:

      - Is **symbol version** of import different to symbol found in used unit? If so, recompile needed.
- If DCU is not found, source will need to be found and compiled, otherwise compile-time error

The important concept is that of **symbol version**. When saving a DCU, Delphi calculates a hash based on the **interface declaration** of the symbol and associates it with the symbol. Other units that use the symbol also store the symbol version. In this way, link-time conflicts caused by stale symbols are avoided, unlike most C linkers.

The upshot of this is that you should be able to add Classes.pas to your project and modify its **implementation** section almost to your heart's content, and still be able to **statically** link with the rest of the RTL and VCL and third-party libraries, even those provided in object format only.

Things to be careful of:

- Inlined routines; the body of inlined routines are part of the symbol version
- Generics; the implementation side of generic types and methods are part of the respective symbol versions

Comment: Also, he should change a copy of Classes.pas and add to project, avoiding updates problems.

Comment: OK, I took a copy of Classes.pas and added it to my project. Couldn't build because of symbol version issues as described above. Tried setting all the compiler options as per question "D2009 VCL unit that won't compile' without joy. As I was going to need to modify the public interface anyway, didn't pursue this any further.