# Delphi XE4: the form size reduced

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, vcl, delphi-xe4, win64

I created the new program and testing it on the different OS - windows 7 and 8 (64-bit).

In windows 8 (64-bit) I see the size of a form is normal.
In windows 7 (64-bit) I see the size of a form is very reduced, especially on width.

I found the solve here: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=113544.
I corrected of Vcl.Forms.pas,  but it for me not work!

How can I solve it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The problems with sizes of the form is remained. In windows 7 (64-bit) I see the size of a form is very reduced, especially on width.

Comment: Delphi used the original VCL unit which is precompiled. You can convince yourself if you will write some nonsense which would prevent code from compilation into that unit. Follow e.g. [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10471855/960757) for solution.

Comment: My steps:

1. I copy of original the file VCL.Forms.pas to a folder of the my project.
2. I modify original the file VCL.Forms.pas as here:  http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=113544
3. Then - build my a project and compile (platform 64-bit). In folder \Win64\Debug\ is VCL.Forms.dcu compiled!
4. Testing on OS Windows 7 (64-bit) - is have not change! The problems with sizes of the form is remained.

What I do wrongly?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You use monolithic EXE or BPLs? And you can run SysIntetnals Process Monitor and see which Forms pas and/or DCUs Delphi searches for when building your program. PS. More reliable solution I think is in-memory patch of binary code if possible. PPS which of two Forms.pas files did you modified? Did you added it to the project explicitly?  Can you set breakpoint in the Code you modified?

Comment: Also do you use VCL or FMX? At least I don't think you are using dotNet so I remove dotNet tag

Comment: Excuse me, your explanation very is not clear, I the beginning programmer and me it is necessary to find the most simple solution of a problem. I compiled a copy of original file VCL.Forms.pas directly in my project. At addition to the my project VCL.Forms.pas I receive the message that such module is already added. Please, write step by step my actions to compile changed VCL.Forms.pas. Changed file VCL.Forms.pas needs to be renamed or not? Thanks

Comment: Those are not explanations, those were questions about your project and suggestions how to investigate what happens.  Please address them one by one.