# compile DELPHI code with different compiler directives

Tags: delphi, build

We use Delphi 10 Seattle. Inside our code we use different compiler directives to  produce different exe files, like debug, release version, or versions with different features sets (disable some functions for different customers ...)

Current way of getting the exe files:

- **change compile options by hand manually typing  inside DELPHI IDE ...**
- compile and copy *.exe to a new location by hand

Any way to get this with one button click (faster approach ...)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470943/how-to-recompile-modifications-to-vcl-source-file-menus-pas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a build configuration for each of your different feature sets.

Documentation for build configurations is here: [Build Configurations Overview](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Build_Configurations_Overview). This is the mechanism that the IDE provides for switching between debug and release builds, and there is no reason at all for you not to use the same mechanism to switch between your own configuration sets.

The [option set](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Build_Configurations_Overview#Comparing_Configurations_and_Option_Sets) feature allows you to extract certain sets or groups of options into separate files which can then be applied to configurations. You can apply the same option set multiple times, for instance once on top of a base release configuration, and then again on top of a base debug configuration. The build configuration functionality supports inheritance which makes it possible, with a bit of up-front design, to develop a clean hierarchy of configurations.

This configuration functionality is built on top of msbuild which means that you can use the same configurations in your command line builds. In fact, the fact that you mention changing configurations manually in the IDE is a concern. Building your product is not something that should require manual intervention. It is critically important that you address this and arrange that your build process is automated. You can use tools for this, although it is very easy to write your own simple tools that will invoke msbuild for all the configurations that you need to build. Please don't use the IDE to build for release.

As an aside, build configuration is one area of the product where the functionality of RAD Studio surpasses that offered by Visual Studio, in my view.